# Google Reader API - How do you share by article url as oppose to item id?

Tags: google-reader

I've done a decent amount of research on the unofficial reader api and sifted through other questions, but none of them quite have what I want.  How to share an article if you know the article id is well documented, but I want to know how to share an article if you don't know the id (i.e. how to transform url -> id or how to share directly using the url as a parameter).

I imagine it is possible, because the functionality pretty much mimics the behavior of the awesome "Note in Reader" bookmarklet they have.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "Note in Reader" bookmarklet ends up sending a POST to http://www.google.com/reader/api/0/item/edit with these parameters:

- `client`: your client ID
- `T`: action token
- `url`: item url
- `title`: title (interpreted as plain text)
- `snippet`: body (interpreted as HTML)
- `share`: true or false
- `tags`: additional tag to apply to the created note, e.g. user/-/label/foo (optional, repeat the parameter if you wish to add mutliple tags)
- `srcUrl`: URL of the source site
- `srcTitle`: title of the source site

Comment: Thanks, I'd actually come across that before in the context of people adding buttons to their own blogs.  I assume reader just generates a snippet with javascript then.

Comment: http://www.google.com/support/reader/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=147149 mentions similar parameters, but that's for generating the "Note in Reader" form. The POST request above bypasses that and creates the shared item directly.

Comment: Did the above parameters changed lately? I've googled the same issue, and it seems like everybody is now getting a "401 Unauthorized" Error right now.. Which I also get, though I'm authorized (have a SID and a token), any idea what happened?

Comment: @Shady: SID cookies are no longer supported for API authentication (see http://groups.google.com/group/fougrapi/browse_thread/thread/e331f37f7f126c00 and http://code.google.com/p/google-reader-api/wiki/Authentication for more details, and feel free to post in that group if you still have trouble).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll be testing it soon, I just tried to search the group before and got another post that didn't lead me anywhere and thought it was something wrong with my code.. Thanks once more :)